# What does the ATR72-600 MFD System display look like?

Tags: electrical-system, display, atr-72

I'm curious how MFD System display looks in real life in ATR72-600, especially electrical mode. I've found three different images showing it, but they seems to be ambiguous. Last one attached comes from FCOM, two others from other docs. Which one is closest to real life? Buses symbols should be as rounded corner rectangles or simple one? States (like "OFF", "SHED") should be out or inside rectangles? Maybe it depends on software version or some specal mode? Maybe someone has real life photos showing it? Any info is highly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Two "black" images come from "User guide for Engineers" from Thales Avionics, last one as i said from FCOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two actual photos of the electrical systems pages (AC and DC respectively). Hope it helps.

[image: DC electrical system page]

[image: AC/HYD system page]

Comment: Sorry for being late. Thanks for these priceless photos! Right now everything is much more clear and i could move forward with work ;).

Answer (score 2):

For me, it looks like the first picture is something like a screenshot. It looks real. (A bit blurred and pixelated)

The second one looks like a graphic made in a graphics program. There can be small deviations from the original screen design, because it's only for informational purposes.

The third one is a black/white graphic that is made for printing (in the FCOM). I think it should be showing the real MFD quite close to reality because pilots must see it as in real life. But this saves printer color and has more contrast.

I am pretty sure, the first one is a real screenshot. It shows commonalities with the drawing in the FCOM and it looks real.